# Ignore field when inserting with Fluent Nhibernate

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

In my MySql database i have a field which is a timestamp. MySQL is inserting the time when the row is created and updates the time when a row is updated.

How do I tell NHibernate don't to insert anything in that field when inserting and updating. I still want to be able to read the property.

With my current mapping:

```
Map(x => x.CreateDate).Column("CreateDate");
```

NHibernate tries to insert 0001-01-01 00:00:00, because the field is not nullable (And it should not be nullable)

I'm using Fluent Nhibernate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you should be able to add `ReadOnly()` to get that effect.

```
Map(x => x.CreateDate).Column("CreateDate").ReadOnly();
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should specify that property is generated by database:

```
Map(x => x.CreateDate).Column("CreateDate").Generated.Always();
```

Comment: This won't prevent you from being able to perform updates on that column, which I think is desired in this case.

Comment: @ddc0660 You are right, it will be possible to update that column by NHibernate if need be. Generated is useful in case you want to force NHibernate to select that inserted value back to application. Perhaps both should be used here.
BTW, there is a good explanation about property mapping on [Ayende blog](http://ayende.com/blog/3936/nhibernate-mapping-property).